# Dense Rank C# DataTable Using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following SQL that's overly complicated and I'm trying to convert it into LINQ.

I don't think I have to nest LINQ like these statements since the partitioning doesn't use the nested dense ranks but I'm not sure if that's true.

My plan is to make new columns in C# based on each individual dense rank statement. For example, dt["L"] would be equal to the following LINQ. But I can't figure out what the LINQ should be and if I can break this nesting.

Example snippet:

```
"DENSE_RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY   a0.[C]  ,   a0.[G]   ORDER BY    a0.[J]    DESC) AS [L]"
"...WHERE [L] = 1 "

var res = from element in dt.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(x => new { C = x["C"], G = x["G"] })
    .Select( x => x)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x["J"]).First();
```

Full SQL:

```
SELECT /*L3*/  DISTINCT 
          [A] AS [A]
         ,[B] AS [B]
         ,[C] AS [C]
         ,[D] AS [D]
         ,[E] AS [E]
         ,[F] AS [F]
         ,[G] AS [G]
         ,[H] AS [H]
         ,[I] AS [I]
         ,[J] AS [J]
         ,[K] AS [K]
FROM
(
SELECT /*L2*/ 
          [A] AS [A]
         ,[B] AS [B]
         ,[C] AS [C]
         ,[D] AS [D]
         ,[E] AS [E]
         ,[F] AS [F]
         ,[G] AS [G]
         ,[H] AS [H]
         ,[I] AS [I]
         ,[J] AS [J]
         ,[K] AS [K]
         ,[L] AS [L]
         ,[M] AS [M]
         ,DENSE_RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY  [C], [D], [E], [K]   ORDER BY  [H]  DESC) AS [N]
FROM
(
SELECT /*L1*/ 
          [A] AS [A]
         ,[B] AS [B]
         ,[C] AS [C]
         ,[D] AS [D]
         ,[E] AS [E]
         ,[F] AS [F]
         ,[G] AS [G]
         ,[H] AS [H]
         ,[I] AS [I]
         ,[J] AS [J]
         ,[K] AS [K]
         ,[L] AS [L]
         ,DENSE_RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY   [C]  ,   [G]   ORDER BY     [K]     DESC) AS [M]
FROM
(
SELECT /*L0*/  
          a0.[A] AS [A]
         ,a0.[B] AS [B]
         ,a0.[C] AS [C]
         ,a0.[D] AS [D]
         ,a0.[E] AS [E]
         ,DENSE_RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY  a0.[C] ,  a0.[D]  ORDER BY  a0.[E]  ASC) AS [F]
         ,a0.[G] AS [G]
         ,a0.[H] AS [H]
         ,a0.[I] AS [I]
         ,a0.[J] AS [J]
         ,a0.[K] AS [K]
         ,DENSE_RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY   a0.[C]  ,   a0.[G]   ORDER BY    a0.[J]    DESC) AS [L]
FROM 
[table] a0
) t /*L0*/
WHERE
              [L] = 1 
) t /*L1*/
WHERE
              [M] = 1 
) t /*L2*/
WHERE
              [N] = 1 
ORDER BY
           [K] Desc
```

Comment: can you give an example of your initial datatable that comes back from your query and what you'd like the result to be after your linq query?

Comment: Could you have any worse SQL?

Comment: Do you need to use a `DataTable`? LINQ mixed with `DataTable`s generates a fair amount of overhead, is your original data available as an `IEnumerable<T>` for some class T
?